# Exporting Firebase Users Data to Json file format using python

Tags: python, json, firebase

I am trying to get the user ids, signup date and their email addresses from the firebase account to json file using python so that I can just run the command everyday and get the users data updated everyday instead of copy/paste everyday. I have never worked with JSON using python ever before. My boss has provided me 2 links for help which are very useful but I don't know how to write the exact code in Python to get it working. The links he provided me are as follows:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth
- https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/importing-data-from-json-resource-with-python

screenshot of the data I require

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

```py
from firebase_admin import auth

# Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
page = auth.list_users()
while page:
    for user in page.users:
        print('User: ' + user.uid)
    # Get next batch of users.
    page = page.get_next_page()

# Iterate through all users. This will still retrieve users in batches,
# buffering no more than 1000 users in memory at a time.
for user in auth.list_users().iterate_all():
    print('User: ' + user.uid)
```

The above code is from that link. Want you want to do is refactor it and save the users into a dictionary and then export that dictionary as JSON.

```py
from firebase_admin import auth
import json

users = {}

for user in auth.list_users().iterate_all():
    users[user.id] = user

with open("output.json", "w") as outfile: 
    json.dump(users, outfile)
```

Or some variation of the above that works to your liking, could be a list of users instead.

```py
from firebase_admin import auth
import json

users = []

for user in auth.list_users().iterate_all():
    users.append(user)

with open("output.json", "w") as outfile: 
    json.dump(users, outfile)
``
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.This was really helpful. If you may can you please also add the arguments to the code (code from the link) to get the identifier(email address) and signin date(date) as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Read the documentation, trust me. Otherwise `print(user)` and see what stuff it has inside. *cough* user.email *coughcough*

Comment: i got this error message UserObject has no attribute iterate_all() , Can you help me please !